# Unpacking a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pytorch, unpack

I have a custom dataset where data has been stored as dictionary in the form,

file1.pt
{tensor1:tensor2}
file2.pt
{tensor1:tensor2} . and so on goes on for about 50k files gathering 20GB volume.

Tensor1 is the data and Tensor2 is its label. What would be the best way to retain the tensors, or best load into a dataloader as tensors and not dict_keys or dict_values types from all the files.

I currently have all the dictionaries loaded into a dataset.

using "dict.keys()" and "dict.values()", needs to be cast into list then further processed. I'm looking for something quicker.

Comment: Do you mean tensor1 is thre label and tensor2 is the data? Also what does your dataset look like once you "have all the dictionaries loaded" into it?

Comment: How are these files created and loaded? Are you using `torch.save()` and `torch.load()`?

Comment: @JonSG yes, as far as I know, it was saved using torch.save(). And am loading using th.load().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a custom dataset class that overrides the **getitem** and **len** methods. By doing so, you can ensure that the data is loaded lazily, rather than all at once, which should be more memory-efficient.

```
class CustomTensorDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, file_paths):
    self.file_paths = file_paths

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.file_paths)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    file_path = self.file_paths[idx]
    data_dict = torch.load(file_path)
    return data_dict["tensor1"], data_dict["tensor2"]

# Collect file paths
folder_path = "./your_data_folder"
file_paths = [os.path.join(folder_path, fname) for fname in os.listdir(folder_path) if fname.endswith('.pt')]

# Initialize custom dataset and DataLoader
custom_dataset = CustomTensorDataset(file_paths)
data_loader = DataLoader(custom_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: yea, I do have a customDataset class. but my tensors are massive and needs updates for 50k files.